# Getting org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.UnsupportedNotationException while trying to build java classes from wsdl

Tags: java

I am trying to generate java classes from a wsdl file.But while compiling i got following exception
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.UnsupportedNotationException: Cannot convert org.gradle.jacobo.plugins.extension.JaxbExtension_Decorated@2dcf7179 to a task.

I am using Gradle, my gradle file has following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7.0.1622")
    classpath("gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:1.7.1")
    classpath("de.aaschmid:gradle-cpd-plugin:1.2")
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.21")
    classpath ("no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10")
    classpath ("com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.5")
}
```

}

```
plugins {
war
java
maven
idea
id("org.springframework.boot") version "1.5.19.RELEASE"
id("net.ltgt.errorprone") version "0.7.1"
id("no.nils.wsdl2java") version "0.10"
id("com.github.jacobono.jaxb") version "1.3.5"
jacoco
kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.30"
```

}

also added following task for building the schema

```
 task wsdljava {
def generatedWsdlDir = file("src/main/generated-schemas/xjc")  // target directory for generated source code
def wsdlsToGenerate = [   //  2d-array of wsdls and cxf-parameters
                      ["src/main/resources/xsd/wsdl"],
]
 doLast {
     generatedWsdlDir.mkdirs()
     ant.taskdef(
             name: 'xjc',
             classname: 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task',
             classpath: configurations.wsdljava.asPath

     )
     ant.generatedWsdlDir = generatedWsdlDir
     ant.xjc(destdir:generatedWsdlDir, removeOldOutput:'yes', extension:true) {
         System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
         schema(dir:wsdlsToGenerate, includes:'**/*.wsdl')
         depends(dir:schemaSources, includes:'**/*.wsdl')
         produces(dir:generatedWsdlDir, includes:'**/*.java')
     }
 }
```

}

can someone please help what caused the error??